# What's the meaning of "Into the stone sky"?

Tags: meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning

> When ordered to move
>
> *Into the stone sky*.

resource: https://moapyr.fandom.com/wiki/Perun_Flagship/Quotes

What's "the stone sky"?

---

Does it have anything to do with "firmament"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is a metaphor.  Some metaphors are idioms, but this one is not, it has been written by the author.  It means that the sky is like a stone, in some way, perhaps it is grey or mottled, like stone.

Note that this is a canned phrase for a Russian unit in game, and some of the language seems to make it seem more "Russian", so may not be good examples of natural dialogue.

Comment: +1 Stone sky...and the OP says this is a metaphor. How can we interpret in (an)other ways....

Answer (score 2):

I am going to have to caveat this with the fact that I know nothing about the game in question, but the unit looks to be a helicopter called Perun.

Perun is the name of a Slavic god of thunder and lightning.

So, when you order the helicopter to move, it flies to its destination, i.e. takes to the sky. And a stormy sky is grey, the color of many types of stone.